# How to start the Job at startup while using Spring Batch 5 as I am using @EnableBatchProcessiong due to custom Jackson Serializer?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-batch, deserialization

I am migrating from SB 2.x to SB 3.x and I am aware that @EnableBatchProcessing or extending DefaultBatchConfiguration will back of auto starting of jobs but as i need to use a custom JacksonSearlizer i am using @EnableBatchProcessing(executionContextSerializerRef="myJacksonSerializer")

Can help to suggest how can i takecontrol and start the Job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the code that launches the job in the `main` method that starts your Spring Boot application, something like:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

Another option is put that code in an `ApplicationRunner` bean. Here is an example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner jobRunner(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job job) {
        return args -> jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

Comment: I also wanted to mention that there is a feature request to customize the execution context serializer : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/38328

Comment: In my case the parameters are dynamic so I am creating a bean JobLauncherApplicationRunner in the JobConfig class


It solved the problem but is it valid/right approach? - bcz I see testcases are failing